# Tomcat running on Intellij doesn't seem to find the right path to JAVA

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

### Introduction

I've been assigned to an old Java Facets application, and in order to do my work I have to do a reverse ingeneering task first, hence running the project on my machine.

### Problem

So the project seems to build fine and it's supposed to run on a Tomcat 7 server but it's been 3 days now and i've tried pratically everything I could think of to fix this single output :

```
/home//.jdks/temurin-17.0.3/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /tmp/classpath1653361017.jar com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 40057 org.jetbrains.idea.tomcat.agent.TomEEAgent
/home//apache-tomee-plume-7.0.9/bin/catalina.sh run
[2022-05-11 09:49:54,280] Artifact MyProject:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
/home/azesa/apache-tomee-plume-7.0.9/bin/catalina.sh: line 427: /var/lib/snapd/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/353/bin/java: No such file or directory
Disconnected from server
```

### Stuff I tried

- I tried to manually configure the catalina.sh but ended up breaking it.
- I changed the /etc/profile file and added two export statements one of the JAVA_HOME and the other for the CATALINA_HOME
- I have also copied the WAR file in the /webapps directory trying to run doirectly, but it's too messy and it oesn't seem to work

Please HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run TomEE 7, you need to use Java 7 or Java 8.

Your log indicate, that you try to run with Java 17, which won't work. Java 17 ist only supported in TomEE 8.0.11 (Jakarta EE 8) or TomEE 9.0.0+M8-SNAPSHOT (Jakarta EE 9.1).

In addition, it looks like your Environment variables (JAVA_HOME) point to a non existing Java executable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after changing the project JDK, and intelli's default jdk and setting the JAVA_HOME directory the project runs perfectly.